# A Java class for calculating size of iterable/array

Tags: java, generics

Another exercise of Java generics:

```
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 16/11/14.
 */
public class Size {
    public static <T, I extends Iterable<T>> int size(I data) {
        final int size;
        if (data instanceof Collection) {
            size = ((Collection<T>) data).size();
        } else {
            int counter = 0;
            for(Object i : data) {
                counter++;
            }
            size = counter;
        }
        return size;
    }

    public static int size(int[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(double[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(String[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }
}




import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 16/11/14.
 */
public class TestSize {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] x = {1, 2, 3};
        List<Integer> y = new ArrayList<>();
        y.add(1);
        y.add(2);
        System.out.println(Size.size(x));
        System.out.println(Size.size(y));
    }
}
```

Comment: [Follow-up question](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/69976/9357)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arrays, you are missing a generic `int size(Object[] data)` method, which can be written as:

```
public static <E> int size(E[] data) {
     return data.length;
}
```

This will apply to `String[]` as well. You will still need one for each kind of primitive though (boolean, short, int, long, float, double, did I miss anything?)

As for your other method...

```
public static <T, I extends Iterable<T>> int size(I data) {
```

This one can be cleaned up significantly.

You don't need the `<T>` here. In fact, you don't need the `<I>` either. It doesn't matter what kind of iterable it is so you can use `Iterable<?>`.

As you're not defining a variable of type `I` anywhere in your method, nor is using that type in another obscure way, all you're really interested in is that it is an `Iterable<T>`. So:

```
public static <T> int size(Iterable<T> data) {
```

Will have the same effect.

Now, are you using the type `<T>` ? No. In fact, you are iterating over `Object` so all you're interested in is that it is `Iterable<? extends Object>`. Which is the same as `Iterable<?>` since all classes extends Object.

So now we are left with this:

```
public static int size(Iterable<?> data) {
    final int size;
    if (data instanceof Collection) {
        size = ((Collection<?>) data).size();
    } else {
        int counter = 0;
        for (Object i : data) {
            counter++;
        }
        size = counter;
    }
    return size;
}
```

And when introducing early return, this:

```
public static int size(Iterable<?> data) {
    if (data instanceof Collection) {
        return ((Collection<?>) data).size();
    }
    int counter = 0;
    for (Object i : data) {
        counter++;
    }
    return counter;
}
```

Now *that's* a method.

---

Side note: The only method you have that is actually useful is `int size(Iterable<?> data)`. Otherwise it would be easier to just use `data.length` or `data.size();`. However, I understand that this is just an exercise in which case it's fine.

Comment: What I am aiming at is an unified interface of get the size of an array-like object. Thanks for the review! A question, why can't `T[]` cover `int[]`, `short[]` etc?

Comment: @qed `T[]` is an array of some kind of objects. `int[]` is an array of ints. An int is not an object. An int is a *primitive*.

Comment: @qed I don't really see a big benefit of having a unified interface for that. When you're using an array, you know that it's an array so you use `.length`. When you have a `Collection`, you know that it's a collection so you use `.size()`. When you have an `Iterable`, then you're most often not interested in counting the number of items in it, only iterating through them.