# A Java class for calculating size of iterable/array v2

Tags: java, generics

Version 2 of [A Java class for calculating size of iterable/array](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/69974/a-java-class-for-calculating-size-of-iterable-array)

```
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * Created by IDEA on 16/11/14.
 */
public class Size {
    public static int size(Iterable<?> data) {
        if (data instanceof Collection) {
            return ((Collection<?>) data).size();
        }
        int counter = 0;
        for (Object i : data) {
            counter++;
        }
        return counter;
    }

    public static int size(int[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(double[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(float[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(short[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(boolean[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static int size(char[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }

    public static <T> int size(T[] data) {
        return data.length;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (data instanceof Collection) {
    return ((Collection<?>) data).size();
}
```

This looks like it was meant to improve performance for big collections. But, that `instanceof` will prevent certain compiler optimizations and you will get huge performance hit for smaller collections. It's likely not worth it, as most collections are small. This could be avoided by having separate method for `Collections` and `Iterables`.

Universal utilities like this improve neither readability nor performance. I do not see how `Size.size(x)` is more readable than `x.length` or `x.size()`. The only benefit is that you don't have to think which one to use.

I would leave only method for calculating the size of Iterables and use `size()`/`length` for collections/arrays.

```
/**
 * Created by IDEA on 16/11/14.
 */
```

Such comments aren't really useful.

```
public class Size {
```

I would make the class final and the constructor private as there is no reason to extend or instantiate class with only static methods.